# Autofill Service isn't shown in setting autofill service list in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-autofill-manager

I'm trying to develop a simple app that uses Autofill Framework in Android Oreo for autofill email in the other apps. I just clone, build and run this project
https://github.com/googlearchive/android-AutofillFramework
but my application does not show in Autofill Service  in the setting autofill service list.
Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: No idea, I have the exact same question. I even have a smaple repo here showcasing my problem:
https://github.com/sleaper/react-native-autofill/commit/090d73cba7caa9574f81cb6d55e9e5705ac2b141

Answer (score 0):

Apps that provide autofill services must include a declaration that describes the implementation of the service. To specify the declaration, include a  element in the app manifest. The  element must include the following attributes and elements:

**android:name** attribute that points to the subclass of AutofillService in the app that implements the service.

**android:permission** attribute that declares the BIND_AUTOFILL_SERVICE permission.

**intent-filter** element whose mandatory  child specifies the android.service.autofill.AutofillService action.

Optional **meta-data** element that you can use to provide additional configuration parameters for the service.

The following example shows an autofill service declaration:

```
<service
            android:name=".MyAutofillService"
            android:label="My Autofill Service"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_AUTOFILL_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.autofill.AutofillService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.autofill"
                android:resource="@xml/service_configuration" />
        </service>
```

Refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services for details.